# Proper use of strcat() in C

Tags: c

I have an archive file that looks like this:

```
!<arch>
file1.txt/      1350248044  45503 13036 100660  28        `
hello
this is sample file 1
```

Now in here, the number 28 in the header is the `file1.txt` size. To get that number, I use:

```
  int curr_char;
  char file_size[10];
  int int_file_size;

  curr_char = fgetc(arch_file);

  while(curr_char != ' '){
    strcat(file_size, &curr_char);
    curr_char = fgetc(arch_file);
  }

 // Convert the characters to the corresponding integer value using atoi()
 int_file_size = atoi(file_size);
```

However, values in the `file_size` array change every time I run my code. Sometimes it's correct, but mostly not. Here are some examples of what I get for `file_size`:

?28`U

2U8U

28    <--- Correct!

pAi?28

I believe the problem is with my strcat() function, but not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `strcat` is for strings.

Comment: well I tried changing curr_char to char, but that doesn't work either

Comment: a single char is not a string.

Comment: «I believe the problem is with my strcat() function, but not sure» — Sure, it has to have some AI built-in to be able to do exactly what you meant it to do.

Comment: Another hint. If you're using an `int` to store a string, it can be misleading and the problems with it can be hidden if you use a little endian machine. If you store the `A` character in an `int` internally, it would look something similar to this: `A\x0\x0\x0` because the least significant value is stored first. This, coincidentally, happens to be a valid, null-terminated string. However, this is dodgy practice and will break on big endian machines.

Comment: I would say there is no such thing as *proper* use of `strcat` in C. In the situations where you know it's safe to use, you already have sufficient information to perform the operation much more efficiently with `strcpy` or `memcpy`. In situations where you don't know it's safe, it's not proper to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't read the file character wise. There are higher level functions doing this. As larsmans already pointed out, you can use `fscanf()` for this task:

```
fscanf(arch_file, "%d", &int_file_size);
```

Comment: Well in this case, how can I check to see if the current character is white-space or not? Because the file size can be anything from 1 to 10 characters long, and if it's less that 10, the rest would be whitespaces.

Comment: `fscanf()` skips leading white space and then reads digits and interprets it as a number (`%d`). Look for the manual of `fscanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

`&curr_char` is an `int*`, so you're copying over the bits of an `int` as if they represented a string.

You should be using `scanf`.

Comment: @programmer93: `strcat` can only handle two strings.

Comment: @programmer93: no, because it wants a null-terminated string. Switch to `scanf` if you want to parse numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&curr_char` points to a single character (well, actually an integer as that's how you declared it). `strcat` looks for a string, and string as you should know are terminated by a `'\0'` character. So what `strcat` does in your case is use the `&curr_char` pointer as the address of a *string* and looks for the terminator. Since that is not found weird stuff will happen.

One way of solving this is to make `curr_char` an array, initialized to zero (the string terminator character) and read into the first entry:

```
char curr_char[2] = { '\0' };  /* Will make all character in array be zero */

...

curr_char[0] = fgetc(...);
```

There is also another problem, and that is that you are trying to concatenate into a string that is not initialized. When running your program, the array `file_size` can contain *any* data, it's not automatically zeroed out. This leads to the weird characters *before* the number. This is solved partially the same way as the above problem, by initializing the array:

```
char file_size[10] = { '\0' };
```